# Unable to locate Xpath of SVG element

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath, automation

Unable to locate xpath of SVG element. Here is HTML part of SVG

```
<visual-modern _ngcontent-qqf-c10="" _nghost-qqf-c17="">
<div _ngcontent-qqf-c17="" class="visual visual-card allow-deferred-rendering" focus-nav-mode="Group" initialized="">
<svg width="146.60231660231662" height="65.98455598455598" class="card setFocusRing" tabindex="0" focusable="true" aria-label="Total Sales Reps 171." pbi-focus-tracker-idx="3">
<g transform="translate(73.30115830115831,36.98446549227799)"><text class="value" style="text-anchor: middle; fill: rgb(162, 123, 53); font-family: wf_standard-font, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 32px; white-space: pre;">171<title>171</title></text></g><g transform="translate(73.30115830115831,61.00009049227799)"><text class="label" style="fill: rgb(80, 62, 27); font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-anchor: middle; white-space: pre;">Total Sales Reps<title>Total Sales Reps</title></text></g><div class="caption" style=""></div></svg></div></visual-modern>
```

Relative and Absolute Xpath already tired.

```
<visual-modern _ngcontent-qqf-c10="" _nghost-qqf-c17="">
<div _ngcontent-qqf-c17="" class="visual visual-card allow-deferred-rendering" focus-nav-mode="Group" initialized="">
<svg width="146.60231660231662" height="65.98455598455598" class="card setFocusRing" tabindex="0" focusable="true" aria-label="Total Sales Reps 171." pbi-focus-tracker-idx="3">
<g transform="translate(73.30115830115831,36.98446549227799)"><text class="value" style="text-anchor: middle; fill: rgb(162, 123, 53); font-family: wf_standard-font, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 32px; white-space: pre;">171<title>171</title></text></g>
<g transform="translate(73.30115830115831,61.00009049227799)"><text class="label" style="fill: rgb(80, 62, 27); font-family: &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, wf_segoe-ui_normal, helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-anchor: middle; white-space: pre;">Total Sales Reps<title>Total Sales Reps</title></text></g><div class="caption" style=""></div></svg></div></visual-modern>
```

Comment: https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYmI0NTU1YTQtODYxMC00N2ZjLWI4MDgtNzBiZWJkNjIzOWFjIiwidCI6ImJkM2ZjNmFlLWE0NTUtNGFlYS1hM2RiLTI4NzlkMjI1MzM4NiIsImMiOjEwfQ%3D%3D need to locate elements in this

Comment: Can you show me what you tried?

Comment: Which selenium language binding here? what is your expected output to be return?

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to select svg element with aria-label attribute with value 'Total Sales Reps 171.', like this:

```
//svg[@aria-label='Total Sales Reps 171.']
```

It should work if aria-label value is unique.
To buildup your xpath knowledge you could check out this [document](http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf) with some xpath recipes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys for help. Here is the Solution

/*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g'][1]/*[name()='g']/*[1]